css `overflow:auto` is overflowing from flex container by size of fixed width children
I have some really strange CSS riddle to you guys:
consider the following tree:

app container

flex container

item1 - fixed width(80px)
item2 - responsive width(width:100%).

MUI Stepper - overflow:scroll, width:100%







this would look similar to this:

note: MUI Stepper width and item2 width are equal here(as intended). MUI Stepper width is 100% of item2 which is 100% of the space width left for item2 (which is flex container width - item1 width).
so far so good, awesome.
now what happens if we shrink the size of the screen to become smaller then the minimum width MUI Stepper content is requiring? well, I would expect a scroll bar to appear in the stepper, and MUI Stepper should keep being 100% of flex container.width - item1.width, and should not overflow outside of its parent item2.
actual result:

the width of the 'glitch' directly related to the width of the first children in the flex box (item1). if the width of the first item is 20 then the glitch width would be 20 also:

my question is, why does it appear that when MUI Stepper has enough space for its content its size 100% of the space left for item2, and when the screen get squeezed and there not enough size for the stepper content then MUI Stepper gets the size of the flex container parent item?
I know I can do something like width:"calc(100% - 80px)" in MUI Stepper. i want to avoid it(if possible).
a good explanation would be welcomed. i could not understand this effect from any docs i found. thanks in advance!
demo app here

well, the solution was setting overflow: 'hidden' on item 2. will keep this answer for other users who might stumble upon this issue.
but now have other question, how is that hidden here actually fix the issue and not just hiding the visible overflowing content from the stepper to item2? even after decades of learning css you might fing yourself confused sometimes 
amazingly enough answered to me by claude ai(CGPT or Gemini wasn't able to help. claude gave full accurate response in one shot!).
